# Is it possible to create a hidden txt file in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am constructing an app in Visual Studio. I need to create some files to be used in a dll, but I want the files to be hidden when viewing the folder. How can I do this in a C++ program?

Interactively, you can mark a file has hidden by right-clicking on it, selecting "Properties" and selecting "Hidden". The question is, how can do something equivalent from a C++ program?

Comment: What do you mean by hidden?

Comment: When you push the right button of the mouse in a file appears a menu, you select properties and appears a window of properties of the file, you in 'attriubutes' you can choose 'read only' or 'hidden' (this is what I want)

Comment: There is no portable way to create hidden files either in C or in C++.

"Hidden files" are a Windows-specific feature. You'll have to use some Windows-specific code to mark a file has hidden.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes and close votes. The question seems clear enough.

Comment: so just set `hidden` attribute for your files! :-) :-D

Comment: @Alex, ok but how can I do this within c?

Comment: show us how do you create them in C ?

Comment: C or C++? They're two different languages. It sounds like you're using C++, so just stick with that. (The answer might happen to be the same as in C, but there's no point in confusing things.)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx (somebody who actually does Windows programming should feel free to incorporate this into an answer)

Comment: @Alex std::fstream file; int main(){ file.open("myUnhiddenFile.txt",std::ios::out); file << "This is my unhidden file, that I have created just now" ; file.close(); return(0);}

Comment: Oh yes, that's C++, the question was edited

Comment: It wasn't edited in that sense. It was always tagged C++. If you wanted C, you should have asked for C.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`SetFileAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx) function in the Windows API:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

std::fstream file; 
int main(){ 

   file.open("myUnhiddenFile.txt",std::ios::out); 
   file << "This is my unhidden file, that I have created just now" ; 
   file.close();

   wchar_t* fileLPCWSTR = L"myUnhiddenFile.txt"; // To avoid incompatibility
                                                 // in GetFileAttributes()
   int attr = GetFileAttributes(fileLPCWSTR);
   if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0) {
       SetFileAttributes(fileLPCWSTR, attr | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
    }
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: You forgot `#include`s, and a `const`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't forget :-) I have no idea which one I should include :-) so if you can help I would appreciate that a lot :-)

Comment: I'd assume `<windows.h>` from [this example's includes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: `windows.h` does not provide `std::fstream`. Stop guessing and _read the documentation_!!!!!

Comment: I was assuming that Alex knew that one, and was merely unfamiliar with the windows api.

Comment: _"I have no idea which one I should include"_ his first comment here, plus he did not write it in the code.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Sorry, I am not really c++ expert :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD attributes = GetFileAttributes("MyFile.txt");
SetFileAttributes("MyFile.txt", attributes + FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Files created with the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN can be easily seen when checking the "[Hidden Items](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files)" checkbox. The only way to really hide a file is to use a [File System Filter Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/introduction-to-file-system-filter-drivers) that will eliminate the file (or a file/s pattern) record from the results, whenever [NtQueryDirectoryFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile)() is called. Windows File Explorer calls NtQueryDirectoryFile() so with such driver, the file won't show even if "Hidden Items" is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple technique..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
system("echo >file.txt");
system("attrib +h +s file.txt");

return 0;
}
```